# Elbow bending in an odd way

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am busy rigging a character model and trying to weight paint it to finalize it. However, when I use the rig to check for deformities I cannot figure why this particular bending with the elbow causes this shape. I have tried experimenting with different strengths of weights but most of them do not get the result I want. I posted 2 other pictures with the weight painting for the first and second bones. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Image showing the arm armature]

[image: Forearm weight painting]

[image: Upper arm weight painting]

Comment: Three words: Corrective Shape Keys.

Comment: One thing that could cause this is other bones affecting it. Make sure no other bones are affecting the arm